# Salesforce Error: {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'authentication failure'} when attempting to utilize authorization_code to authorize

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, salesforce

When trying to get an access token using the auth_code flow, I get this error: {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'authentication failure'}
Here is my request to https://mysalesforceurl.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token utilizing python

```
data = {
            "grant_type": "authorization_code",
            "redirect_uri": redirect_uri,
            "code": auth_code,
            "code_verifier": code_verifier,
            "client_id": SALESFORCE_CLIENT_ID,
            "client_secret": SALESFORCE_CLIENT_SECRET
        }
        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Basic {auth_header}",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
        response = requests.post(token_url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

I've seen lots of people with a similar error, but none utilizing the auth code flow.

I've already selected "allow users to self-authenticate" and to relax the IP restrictions within my app.
Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In my case that was happening because of the wrong "Host" header. It should be set to the same value as you set to your redirect_uri, or, if you are connecting to the client who has custom domain, that domain should be in the "Host" header instead, like "mydomain.my.salesforce.com".

I couldn't find any documentation regarding this, so figured it out just by testing with different values.